# Is it considered bad practice to compile into Javascript as a matter of language preference?

Tags: javascript, ruby, compilation

I understand that compiling into Javascript is sometimes necessary and even in some cases results in a [faster](http://j15r.com/blog/2013/04/25/Box2d_Revisited) application.

However I'm wondering if compiling into Javascript, for building web applications, from a language like ruby, is considered bad practice. Specifically for the purpose of language preference and for the task of doing typical front-end functions.

Comment: Good question! I've always wondered why so much effort is put into avoiding JavaScript.

Comment: What other language would you use?  Last time I checked, Javascript is the only language universally supported in browsers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey CoffeeScript and TypeScript are examples of languages that cross-compile to JS. I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: @Don. OK. So? It sounds like the OP is describing a server-side language that emits Javascript for the purposes of validation and things like that.  CoffeeScript is already on the client side.  Why add yet another step?

Comment: @Don: The OP was asking why you would compile into JavaScript. RobertHarvey's point is that you would compile into JavaScript because compiling into another language doesn't make any sense. And you have proven his point perfectly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I assumed the "language preference" choice implicit in the OP's question was "Compile language X into JavaScript" versus "Write JavaScript by hand" (rather than "Compile language X into JS" versus "Compile language X into other language Y"), but maybe I've misread (or maybe I'm misunderstanding you're saying). For example, is it bad to use [fay](https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki) to compile Haskell code into JS, just because you're don't want to use JS.

Comment: @apsillers: Then why mention Ruby?  Is there some sort of RubyScript analogue to CoffeeScript that I don't know about?

Comment: @RobertHarvey [There are at least eight](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#ruby); I initially assumed th OP was talking about such a tool. Ruby does enough other things with JS, though, that I'l easily concede that it would very likely be something else, especially since the question seems to be Ruby-specific.

Comment: @apsillers: Alright, my bad.  Personally, I would just write Javascript, although I find [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) interesting.

Comment: I know of several high-level languages that can be compiled into JS (F#, OCaml, C#, I think Google had a Java->JavaScript compiler). Sounds completely fine, as long as it is well-debugged and well-tested.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a bad practice?

Comment: @user16764 I'm not sure if I lean one way or the other. The main reason I ask is because the compiled JS code from Ruby, using opal, isn't necessarily as "clean" as I would expect. Check it out – http://opalrb.org/try/

Comment: @ryanSrich that is my point when I say the performance claims were ridiculous - especially dynamic languages with different semantics from JS need to emit runtime calls everywhere to be correct. So you are then running ruby on top of javascript, which will perform horribly. It could be enough for some toy demos but good luck if you made a real application on top of it. Also Opal does something really nasty to avoid runtime FunctionCall function required for method missing - it defines every possible function on some top level prototype as method missing.

Answer (score 8):

In his article [Javascript is assembly language for the web](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/JavaScriptIsAssemblyLanguageForTheWebSematicMarkupIsDeadCleanVsMachinecodedHTML.aspx) Scott Hanselman argues quite convincingly that JavaScript is a low-level language and that it makes perfect sense where possible to leverage a cross-compiler if that will make you more productive.

The same question could be asked regarding Assembly language. And while many people railed against the concept of higher level languages, they eventually lost that argument, just like the people who complained about the performance lost when using languages like Java and C# that don't compile to machine code but instead are compiled against a virtual machine (JVM or .NET Runtime, respectively).

JavaScript is like IL for the web, the fact that we can use higher-level languages to program JS means that we can be more productive and leverage the compiler to get good enough (and in many cases better) performance makes doing so a very good practice.

When I say low level, I mean metaphorically. Just as C lets us ignore things like registers and the like. Using a cross-compiler let's us ignore things like navigating/manipulating the DOM. We're removing ourselves from the details of what Javascript does and focusing on the logic of the app. This has enabled things like a [full x86 emulator running linux in the browser](http://boingboing.net/2011/05/18/javascript-based-pc.html) or [Unreal engine running in the browser](http://www.extremetech.com/gaming/151900-unreal-engine-3-ported-to-javascript-and-webgl-works-in-any-modern-browser)

To answer Robert Harvey's Question, if you look at projects like LLVM, you can practically choose whatever language you'd like (and thus use whatever tools you like) and have it generate valid Javascript.

Also, as follow up, [Scott asked the creator of JavaScript and the creator of JSON their views on the topic](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/JavaScriptisAssemblyLanguagefortheWebPart2MadnessorjustInsanity.aspx)
Brendan Eich replied:

> I said "JS is the x86 of the web" a couple of years ago [likely at JSConf], but I can't claim it's original. [Nick Thompson said it on Hacker News this year as well.]
>
> The point is JS is about as low as we can go. But it also has higher-level facilities.
>   Shaver's right, assembly without a great macro processor is not good for programmers or safety. JS is. So the analogy needs some qualification or it becomes silly.
>
> The mix of high-level functional programming and memory safety, with low-level facilities such as typed arrays and the forthcoming ES.next extension of typed arrays, binary data, make for a more powerful programming language than assembly, and of course memory safety is the first differentiator.

Comment: What "ridiculous argument" about performance? And I didn't say the performance makes it a good practice, I said the increased productivity. If I'm proficient in Ruby, writing code in Ruby is more productive than writing code in JavaScript. As far as performance being good enough it's how Google+ is run if you had bothered to follow the link you would have seen that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've said here.  But implicit in the OP's question is the notion that there might be some other language choice, and your answer doesn't really address that possibility.

Comment: @MikeBrown Well, the article is about minifying your javascript. I don't see the article saying that running high level languages on top of just as high level language gives acceptable performance or (in many cases better?)

Comment: @MikeBrown I get where you're coming from, but saying that JS is a low level language is a bit mind blowing. If you consider JS to be low level, how would you categorize C? BTW, JS is compiled to an IL by our browsers. It's just that every browser apparently has its own version of that IL.

Comment: @StefanBilliet: Wouldn't it be nice if the IL were under an ECMA standard as well as Javascript?

Comment: Well no. V8 doesn't have IL at all.

Comment: @Esailija It doesn't? So it compiles JS straight to assembly language or what? </noobquestion>

Comment: @Esailija, wrong, there are intermediate languages in v8, see http://floitsch.blogspot.fr/2012/03/optimizing-for-v8-hydrogen.html

Comment: @Esailija, are you confusing performance with productivity?

Comment: @SK-logic I do not think it's useful definition to say IR is IL at all. V8 just has data structures about the code, not IL like [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Bytecodes) or IE has. Although you can use that definition but then what's the point because everything has an IL then unless they somehow directly use the source string without parsing it into IR first.

Comment: @StefanBilliet Yes, code is compiled directly to generic machine code by the general compiler, there is no interpretation at all like in SpiderMonkey. Hot functions then get analyzed and recompiled to specialized code by the optimizing compiler.

Comment: @Esailija, any kind of an intermediate language can be serialised. Especially a flat one. IR in v8 is quite a typical flat SSA representation which can be serialised (into a bytecode or whatever) exactly the same way as LLVM IR or gcc gimple. Having a low level unified, standardised IR would definitely be beneficial, and it's most likely a much better approach than something like asm.js. And, no, v8 does not compile directly into machine code, it is using at least two different abstract machine representations in between.

Comment: @SK-logic By direct I mean Source string -> AST -> machine instructions. That's just one IR. Compiling literally directly from the source string seems absurd to me. This is how V8 is different from spidermonkey, which has "byte codes" or IL, which is interpreted. I believe the original intention was to claim that every engine is like spidermonkey in this sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10339/discussion-between-esailija-and-sk-logic)

Comment: @Esailija, as I said, there are at least two distinct IRs after an AST in v8. And in theory you can interpret each of the IRs and represent them as "bytecode" VMs.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't quite call it a bad practice. However, the further you are removed from JS in the language you're working in (in your case Ruby apparently), the greater the chance that the compiler will create errors. E.g. TypeScript is a close superset of JS, but I imagine that Ruby doesn't share a whole lot with JS (I could be wrong). 
I don't particularly like JS myself, but I found that when trying to circumvent using a language, sooner or later it catches up with you and you'll still be forced to actually use that language. Might as well embrace it from the get-go.